# How to pass commands in command prompt using Python

Tags: python, automated-tests, command-line-interface, command-prompt

How to enter a command in the command prompt using Python?

Using Python I can able to open the cmd but after that, I want to Pass some commands

Comment: use `subprocess` to run commands eg `subprocess.call("-ls -l")`

Comment: Any examples of the command you would like to run and how this would fit into your python program?

Answer (score 0):

subprocess allows you to run commands as following

```
 import subprocess
 subprocess.call("ping google.com")
```

Comment: This will be fine, Using this I can call the cmd and it will open, after that how can I able to pass the command inside the cmd Prompt